# Mobile UI needs some love

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, documentation, mobile-web

Browsing docs.so on mobile is fine-ish. It's editing anything that's painful. The screen scrolls awkwardly to the preview box and then you can't see the actual input box, and you have to zoom out much, or scroll awkwardly (the way things move around when you scroll is quote off-putting at first) to reveal the *submit* button.

[image]

I love browsing and posting from my phone on SE, but docs.so needs to give mobile users a bit of lovin'. I couldn't figure out a way to get to docs.so from the SE Android app either.

Comment: Great, more people using txtspk because they're writing docs on mobile... ;)

Comment: thanks for reporting it. we have it on radar for sure, but there's still a lot of other mobile issues that need to be addressed first. docs isn't mobile optimized now and thats why you have issues with editing. for now it's status-declined but again: we have it on radar!

Comment: @Paweł Isn't that [meta-tag:status-deferred] then?

Comment: @hichris123 it is, good point, i'm updating:)

Comment: Personally think this should be a higher priority. As an aside, why doesn't the regular markdown editor for questions and answers not work? Can you give users the option to use that instead?